# PHPMailer - error cannot instantiate mail function

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailer

I have a script that is sending email to my membership, and it successfully sends emails to the first 141 users, and then fails for the remaining 100+ users (all of which have valid emails.

Anyone have any ideas why it would just stop functioning while in a loop?

I am essentially doing this in a loop:

```
$Log->Notice("Iteration " . $count . ": About to send email to $name ($address)");
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo " - FAILED to send email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>" . $NL;
   $Log->Error("Failed to send email");
   $Log->Error($mail->ErrorInfo);
   $num_fail++;
} else {
   echo " - Email sent" . $NL;
   $Log->Notice("Email successfully sent");
   $num_success++;
}
```

Comment: Is it always the first 141 users? Is there something strange about the email address of the 142nd user in the list?

Comment: Are you running out of memory?

Comment: execution_timeout set to a higher value in php.ini?

Comment: Your hitting a limit of sorts. Think about batching in 50 emails, then next 50, are you doing this with cron?

Comment: local host? shared host? lots of hosts limit the number of emails you can send

Comment: Add sleep(3); after every iteration maybe. also try swiftmailer because, for example, I had encoding problems with phpmailer

Comment: nothing unusual about the email address at 142. I haven't run it enough to know if it always bails out at that exact spot, but I know it never does the whole list. It is a local shared host. Yea, I am wondering if the host is limiting it on me.